# Fill current row on the basis of data available for immidieate prior date in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below given data:

[image: Table]

In the above structure we need to carry forward the immediate prior rating(coulmn 3) rows that don’t have values for Ratings. And final data should be like this :

[image: Final result]

Could anyone help with the sql query for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use running sum to calculate groups when a `null` value is encountered and use `max` to fill the values per group.

```
select date,action,rating,outlook,max(rating) over(partition by grp) as new_rating
from (select t.*
      ,sum(case when rating is null then 0 else 1 end) over(order by date) as grp
      from tbl t
     ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `lag()`:

```
select date, action,
       coalesce(rating, lag(rating) over (order by date)) as rating,
       outcome
from t;
```

You can incorporate this into an update using an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select date, action,
             coalesce(rating, lag(rating) over (order by date)) as as new_rating,
             outcome
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set rating = new_rating;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it is failing in case where 3rd and 4th row needs to be filled by 5th-row rating. It is filling only immediate prior not above it.

Comment: @Preedhi . . . I missed your actual intent because the title of the question is "data available for immidieate prior date in sql server".

Comment: No issues. Thanks a lot for answering